# Visual Studio 2013 RC Professional CodeLens not showing up

Tags: visual-studio-2013, codelens

I have installed Visual Studio 2013 RC  Professional but i am not seeing codelens feature working. Even tried looking for Tools -> Options -> Text Editor -> All Languages -> Code Information Indicators but "Code Information Indicators" option is totally missing.

Any help how can i see codelens in VS2013 RC Prof?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need Visual Studio 2013 **Ultimate** with **Team Foundation Server 2013**.

> To use this feature you will need Visual Studio 2013 Preview and Team
>   Foundation Server 2013 Preview as some information comes from TFS.

and:

> Here's what you’ll need:
>
> - Visual Studio Ultimate 2013 to find references
> - Team Foundation Server 2013 to find changesets, code review requests,
>     and different kinds of work items

[Source](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/zainnab/archive/2013/07/09/visual-studio-2013-preview-codelens-aka-code-information-indicators.aspx)

This [article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dn269218%28v=vs.120%29.aspx) will tell you the same.

You can download Team Foundation Server [here](http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/eng/2013-downloads).

Comment: OH i see..so it need ultimate only. Thanks glautrou